# Efficient method of searching for multiple values in a variable using indexOf()?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, indexof

I am building a condition script that searches a comma-separated list of email recipients. There can be multiple recipients and the condition script searches for three (3) specific addresses.

This is not a full-fledged script - it can only include a conditional statement. Our issue is that this field has a character limit of 255... and we have reached it.

Here is the current condition:

```js
email.recipients.toLowerCase().indexOf('email_1') >= 0 || email.recipients.toLowerCase().indexOf('email_2') >= 0 || email.recipients.toLowerCase().indexOf('email_3') >= 0
```

This is within our character limit - and works - but now we need to add another email address to search for. Is there any way of shortening this condition?

Comment: Can't you use regexps??? Should it be on one line (one statement)?

Comment: _This is not a full-fledged script - it can only include a conditional statement._ - can you be more specific about what this means? What is permitted, precisely?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ES6 (you don't need to worry about Internet Explorer), you can use an arrow function:

```
['email_1','email_2','email_3'].some(e=>email.recipients.toLowerCase().indexOf(e)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `some`:-

```js
['email_1', 'email_2', 'email_3'].some(function(e) {
  return email.recipients.toLowerCase().indexOf(e) >= 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the particular email addresses, a regex solution might be simpler:

```
/email_[1-3]/i.test(email.recipients)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect answer of course, but you can shorten a little bit with using an alias (be careful about var conflicts, because you cannot use the `var` keyword inside this expression, meaning the var will be global, it also might not work in strict mode i think).

Just made an answer because it was too long for a comment.. hope ite helps.

```js
var email = {}; email.recipients = 'email_1,email_2,email_3';
console.log((a = email.recipients.toLowerCase()) && (a.indexOf('email_1') >= 0 || a.indexOf('email_2') >= 0 || a.indexOf('email_3') >= 0));
```